# Getting CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jndi, ejb-3.0, websphere-liberty

I'm creating an EJB application with JPA. I created EJBBean that uses the **@PersistenceContext** with the **Entity Manager**. I also provided the settings in the **Persistence.xml** file that has the **Hibernate** information. I'm trying to use **transaction-type=JTA** and trying to access the **DataSource using the JNDI**. I have also provided some information in the **server.xml** file of the **Websphere Liberty**

However, I'm getting an error message -

**javax.ejb.EJBException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/SolarUniversityJpa reference.  The exception message was: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.**

Please refer to the Error Message mentioned after the Server.xml file for more information

**Servlet**

```
@WebServlet("/StudentServlet")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    StudentEjbBean studentEjbBean;

    public StudentServlet() {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        studentEjbBean.testJpa();
    }

}
```

**EjbBean**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StudentEjbBean {

    @PersistenceContext(name="SolarUniversityJpa")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public StudentEjbBean() {
    }

    public void testJpa()
    {
        StudentDao studentDao = new StudentDaoImpl();
        studentDao.SaveInformation(entityManager);
    }
}
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SolarUniversityJpa"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:global/env/jdbc/MySql</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.student.entity.StudentEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SolarUniversity" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Server.xml**

```
<server description="new server">
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to 
        the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
        id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />

    <jdbcDriver id="mySqlEmbedded" libraryRef="mySqlLib" />
    <library id="mySqlLib" filesetRef="mySqlFileSet" />
    <fileset id="mySqlFileSet" dir="E:/Backups"
        includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar" />

    <dataSource id="jdbc/samplejpadatasource" jndiName="jdbc/MySql"
        jdbcDriverRef="mySqlEmbedded">
        <properties user="root" password="root"
            URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SolarUniversity">
        </properties>
    </dataSource>

    <enterpriseApplication id="SolarUniversityEAR"
        location="SolarUniversityEAR.ear" name="SolarUniversityEAR">
        <!-- <classloader commonLibraryRef="MySQLLib" /> -->
    </enterpriseApplication>
</server>
```

**Exception Information**

```
    [ERROR   ] CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "testMessage". Exception data: javax.ejb.EJBException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/SolarUniversityJpa reference.  The exception message was: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:461)
        at [internal classes]
        at com.ejb.stateless.student.EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.testMessage(EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.java)
        at com.servlet.student.StudentServlet.doPost(StudentServlet.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
        at [internal classes]
    Caused by (repeated) ... : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:960)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 1 more

    [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException:461'
    javax.ejb.EJBException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/SolarUniversityJpa reference.  The exception message was: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:461)
        at [internal classes]
        at com.ejb.stateless.student.EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.testMessage(EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.java)
        at com.servlet.student.StudentServlet.doPost(StudentServlet.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
        at [internal classes]
    Caused by (repeated) ... : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:960)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 1 more

    [ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.ejb.EJBException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/SolarUniversityJpa reference.  The exception message was: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:5000)
        at [internal classes]
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/SolarUniversityJpa reference.  The exception message was: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:461)
        at [internal classes]
        at com.ejb.stateless.student.EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.testMessage(EJSLocalNSLStudentEjbBean_58c656c8.java)
        at com.servlet.student.StudentServlet.doPost(StudentServlet.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by (repeated) ... : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: CWWJP0050E: Unable to locate persistence provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.
        at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.getEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:960)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: If you are using Hibernate 5.2, the provider in your `persistence.xml` to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`. The old ejb class it's looking for is no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is indicating that Hibernate classes cannot be found. This is expected since Liberty does not provide Hibernate classes in the `jpa-2.0` (OpenJPA) or `jpa-2.1` (eclipselink) features.

If you want to use Hibernate with Liberty, you will need to download the Hibernate jars yourself and either include them in your application or configure a shared library.

Assuming you already have the Hibernate jars handy at the location `C:/hibernate`, you could add the following to your server.xml:

```
<library id="HibernateLib">
  <fileset dir="C:/hibernate" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>
```

And then provide the shared library to your application like this:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="SolarUniversityEAR" location="SolarUniversityEAR.ear" name="SolarUniversityEAR">
     <classloader commonLibraryRef="HibernateLib"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

Also, here is a useful sample to work off of:
[Liberty JPA Hibernate Sample](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/opensource-Java_Persistence_API_JPA_Hibernate_Sample)

Comment: This works Absolutely Perfect ! Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: **I'm getting new Exception now:**                                                           [ERROR   ] CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "testMessage" on bean "BeanId(SolarUniversityEAR#SolarUniversityEjb.jar#StudentEjbBean, null)". Exception data: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManager;
  at com.ibm.ws.jpa.container.v21.internal.JPA21Runtime.createEntityManagerInstance(JPA21Runtime.java:104)

Comment: that is a common error for using a version of HIbernate that is pre-JPA 2.1.  Make sure you are using a version of hibernate that is JPA 2.1 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Andy Guibert** for the suggestions. It might be helpful to others. Here is how I fixed the issues.

**For the issue 1:**

I followed the same approach that Andy said.

**For the issue 2:**

> **[ERROR ] CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception
>   during invocation of      method** "testMessage" on bean 
>     "BeanId(SolarUniversityEAR#SolarUniversityEjb.jar#StudentEjb‌​Bean,
>   null)".   **Exception data: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
>     org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManag‌​er(Ljavax/persistenc‌​e/SynchronizationTyp‌​e;Ljava/util/Map;)Lj‌​avax/persistence/Ent‌​ityManager;**
>   **> at
>   com.ibm.ws.jpa.container.v21.internal.JPA21Runtime.createEnt‌​ityManagerInstance(J‌​PA21Runtime.java:104‌​)**

I downloaded the new version of Hibernate that supports the Jpa 2.1. After this, I got another issue

**For the issue 3:**

> CNTR0020E: **EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during
>   invocation of method** "testMessage" on bean
>   "BeanId(SolarUniversityEAR#SolarUniversityEjb.jar#StudentEjbBean,
>   null)". **Exception data: java.lang.NullPointerException**

To fix this, I added following code in the Persistence.xml (Since I'm using **transaction-type="JTA"**). This is specific to the WebSphere Liberty. Source : [7.5.9. org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#services-JtaPlatform)

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
```

And finally, I'm able to save Information in the Database.